# How to format datetime as M/D/YYYY in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

To convert a `datetime` to `MM/DD/YYYY`, this works:

```
declare @datetime datetime = '2015-01-01'
select convert(varchar(10),convert(date,@datetime),101)
```

This evaluates to `01/01/2015`. How can I have the date convert to `1/1/2015` instead?

Nothing on http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx matches the `M/D/YYYY` format.

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server are you using? SQL Server **2012** and newer have a `FORMAT` function - before that, you'd have to do string manipulation yourself...

Comment: Every time I see this question on StackOverflow I say the same thing: Do you REALLY need to do this in SQL? Why not just do it in your user interface, there's almost never a need to do this in the database.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the only possibility you have is to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @datetime DATETIME = '2015-01-01'

SELECT LTRIM(STR(MONTH(@datetime))) + '/' +
       LTRIM(STR(DAY(@datetime))) + '/' +
       STR(YEAR(@datetime), 4)
```

With SQL Server 2012 and above, you can do this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(@datetime, 'M/d/yyyy')
```

Comment: Perfect mate. This helped me a lot and saved days.  <3

Answer (score 5):

```
DECLARE @datetime DATETIME = '2015-01-01';
SELECT STUFF(REPLACE('/' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), @datetime, 101),'/0','/'),1,1,'')
```

This is how it works:

1. First CONVERT the DATETIME to CHAR
2. Then Add a '/' character at the begining
3. REPLACE all '/0' with '/'
4. With STUFF, get rid of the first '/'

Comment: I did @chopper, Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

There's no convert style that uses single digit day or month. This could work, though.

```
declare @datetime datetime = '2015-01-01'
select
    cast(month(@datetime) as varchar(2)) + '/' +
    cast(day(@datetime) as varchar(2)) + '/' +
    cast(year(@datetime) as varchar(4))
```