# how can I format this string to MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#

I have tried a lot of syntax but I can't get it work,

from my DataTable i have this values , please see below

[image]

the above values are from the jQuery datepicker, I just make them values in my query.

C#:
I catch the values from the datepicker using this parameter`

```
    List<DateTime> WeekDates
```

how can i make it to display as 1/6/2016 . thank you for any help!

```
      foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            Sale sales = new Sales();
            sale.WeekStart = row["WeekStart"].ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        }
```

**UPDATE**
is my date values are string or a DateTime already? I catch the values in my webmethod using this

```
List<DateTime> WeekDates, but when it comes to my dataTable it has a single quotes , notice it.
```

Comment: What is the data type of your `row["WeekStart"]` is it a `DateTime` or a `string`?

Comment: the one that will hold the row["WeekStart"] is a string but the actual value of row["WeekStart"] is not existing in the database , it is from the jquery datepicker, I just include it in my query result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all who answered my question. As for now the quick solution for me is to remove unnecessary string to display the format MM/dd/yyyy
using this syntax

```
row["WeekStart"].ToString().Remove(9);
```

Most of you answered the correct syntax to convert it to the MM/dd/yyyy but I figured out that the values of dates from my jQuery datepicker has a single quote value, what I did is removed it before feeding to my SQL parameters and everything works fine. I already used that syntax before I post here , I just need to remove the single quote in my datetime values.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    Sale sales = new Sales();
    var date = Convert.ToDateTime(row["WeekStart"]);
    sale.WeekStart = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); // If sale.WeekStart field is string
}
```

Complete description: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Answer (score 2):

```
[YourDateTimeVarialble].ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: "no overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 argument

Answer (score 2):

```
[date].ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

you can use this one

Answer (score 1):

If those values came from a database, you may want to format them first before populating to your DataTable. For your desired format, you may refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662725/how-to-format-datetime-as-m-d-yyyy-in-sql-server).

**Update 1**
Try formatting your jQuery DatePicker to something like:

```
$(".selector").datepicker({ dateFormat: "MM/dd/yyyy" });
```

**Update 2**

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    Sale sales = new Sales();
    sale.WeekStart = Convert.ToDateTime(row["WeekStart"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: the values are not from the database, it's from jquery datepicker and I make them values in my query.

Comment: Can you try the update I posted? Let's see if that will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(DateTime.ParseExact(row["WeekStart"]), "M/d/YYYY hh:mm:SS tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: hi, it throws an error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: That the issue. What string you are getting?

Comment: `(Convert.ToDateTime(row["WeekStart"].Replace("'","")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");`  I think the row["WeekStart"] has the single brackets.

Comment: @Anonymous: I did this    sale.WeekStart = (DateTime.ParseExact(row["WeekStart"]), "M/d/YYYY hh:mm:SS tt").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); but it says no overload method for ParseExacet takes 1 arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
 string date = "1/6/2016 12:00:00 AM";
 string d = Convert.ToDateTime(date).ToShortDateString();
```

O/P : 1/6/2016

In your case perhaps following code will be useful

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add("Date");
 DataRow row1 = dt.NewRow();
 row1["Date"] = "1/6/2016 12:00:00 AM";
 dt.Rows.Add(row1);
 DataRow row2 = dt.NewRow();
 row2["Date"] = "2/6/2016 12:00:00 AM";
 dt.Rows.Add(row2);

 List<string> WeekStart = new List<string>();

 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
 {
     WeekStart.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(row["Date"]).ToShortDateString());
 }
```

Comment: hi, same error again : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: I think it may work but in my scenario, I need to query in the database and I'm creating my query dynamically and include those datepicker values along with their query result, e.g. total sales in that week, so I should not append it ascendingly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
sale.WeekStart =DateTime.Parse(row["WeekStart"].ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

I think this is work for you

Comment: hi, it throws an error : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: yup you are right! when we parse we give Month starting, but in the case of 1/13/2016 , it suppose 13 as month that's why it throws an exception

Comment: yeah, we use this "MM/dd/yyy" right? why it throws an exception?

Comment: when we put timedate as 1/13/2016, by default compiler sense it as DD/MM/YYYY, so u update compiler that it is a MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: update it to DB from where this come from if that DB is SQL server change this like
SELECT convert(datetime, '1/13/2016', 103)

Comment: if you need more help then go to this link for more details

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
string text = row["Weekstart"].ToString();
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Comment: hi, same error : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.